# How to describe the feeling of being very excited and then get disappointed?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

What is the word that best describes the feeling of getting disappointed when things do not go as you hope? For example, a daughter was expecting to visit her parents this weekend after years apart. She got very excited about it. And then something came up and she couldn't make it.

How do you describe the feeling of being very excited and then getting disappointed?

Comment: What about this situation is not described simply by 'disappointed'?

Comment: @Mitch: Im actually lookinh for a word/phrase that could describe the transition from being hopeful to disappointed.

Comment: You  should edit your question to make that clear, that it is the -change- from excited to disappointed. But to be fair, 'become disappointed' manages this just fine.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest *deflated*.  My dictionary (Chambers, 11th edn) defines *deflate* thiswise:

> (*vt* and *vi*) to collapse or cause to collapse due to emptying of
> gas; **(of one's hopes, ego, etc) to reduce in extent due to
> disappointment, criticism, etc;** (of an economy) to cause deflation in
> or suffer from deflation.

and it's that middle definition (the one I made bold) you're looking for.  To fit the situation in your question one might regard the building up of her excitement as inflation, and the later disappointment as deflation.

Comment: 'punctured his/her ... balloon' is a very similar metaphor. OP has used the wrong tag, but I won't post this as they seem to want a single word.

Comment: Thanks Edwin. I do look for a single word. But phrases and sentences are also appreciated.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: thank you, thats exactly what I need. Cant find the comment box under your answer so I leave my thank-you here.

Answer (score 2):

**Her hopes were dashed.**

> dash someone's hopes.
> Destroy someone's plans, disappoint or disillusion. For example, *That fall dashed her hopes of a gold medal.*
> This term uses dash in the sense of “destroy,” a usage surviving only in this idiom.     [Second half of 1500s].
> — https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dash-someone-s-hopes

Edit: I just realised OP wanted a single word, but I’ll leave this in case it’s useful; anyway, I can’t think of a word that communicates the emotional rollercoaster mentioned!

Comment: Its really helpful k1eran. I'm sure im gonna have to use it some time in the future. Thank you.